# finding multiple modes from a vector of doubles

Tags: c++, mode

So we were asked to get the mode(s) for a vector that the user is going to fill in, it is a vector of doubles, so far i got it working for getting 1 mode, but when it comes to more than 1 mode i freeze, anyone got any suggestions ?(btw im a beginner with coding so don't roast )

```
void getMode(vector<double> v)
{
    double element = 0;
    int freq = 0;

    for (int it = 0; it != v.size(); it++)
    {
        double tempElement = v[it];
        int tempFreq = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
            if (v[i] == tempElement)
                tempFreq++;
        if (tempFreq > freq)
        {
            element = tempElement;
            freq = tempFreq;
        }
     }

    if(freq > 1 )
    { 
        cout << "\nfreq: " << freq <<"\nElement: " << element;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nno mode ";
    }
}
```

so lets say the user inputs 1,1,3,3,4,5
my mode will be only the number 1 instead of 1 and 3, it basically takes the first mode it finds and prints it instead of printing both modes i got.

Comment: Make it into something we can compile and I'm pretty sure you'll have an answer in minutes.

Comment: What Ted is trying to tell you is to study and apply the concept of making a [mcve]. (@Ted, try typing `[mcve]` in future comments like that one.)

Comment: Also please explain what you mean by "i freeze".

Comment: @Yunnosch spot on... thanks for clarifying.

Comment: And please provide some sample data which reproduce the misbehaviour you describe.

Comment: And just to round it off, please take the [tour].

Comment: As it happens I made a `mode`, `average`, `median` kind of thing the other day ... To bad I don't know how that fits into the question.

Comment: @TedLyngmo problem is this is only one function, we're asked to do many functions that's why i can't send the runnable code, mode is basically one function outta 9 but its hard to do, average and median are easy but i just don't know how to find multiple modes, idk how to be better at explaining the situation tbh

Comment: Put what you are trying to describe in your question by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56997802/edit) it. It's an iterative process. We'll bother you about more details until the question is clear. - and hopefully compilable.

Comment: @TedLyngmo done

Comment: Good job, but noone can copy/paste your code and compile it. Add the headers, your `main` - the stuff that makes it "not working".

Comment: @Maad98 How would you find multiple modes with pencil and paper?  Wouldn't you need to store the count of each double somewhere, and when done see which doubles tie for the highest count?  Does your code even come close to this concept?

Comment: Even though there are people like @PaulMcKenzie who are capable of giving hints enough given the limited information you've provided, you do limit your audience by not presenting your problem as best you can. Next time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another example using `unordered_map` to count the frequencies:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map> 
using namespace std;

bool compareFreq(const pair<double,int> &p1, const pair<double,int> &p2) 
{ 
    return (p1.second > p2.second); 
}

void getMode(const vector<double> &v)
{
    unordered_map<double,int> freq_map;
    for (auto elem : v) {
        freq_map[elem]++;
    }
    vector<pair<double,int>> freq_vec(freq_map.begin(), freq_map.end());
    sort(freq_vec.begin(), freq_vec.end(), compareFreq);
    for (auto elem : freq_vec ) {
        cout << elem.first << " : " << elem.second << endl;
    }     
}

int main()
{
    vector<double> v {1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 3.0, 4.0, 3.0, 3.0};

    getMode(v);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

```
3 : 3
1 : 2
4 : 1
2 : 1
```

Comment: u declared a double and an int but never used them in the getMode function, what's the use of them ?

Comment: @Maad98 Thanks! Leftovers from experimentation:)

Answer (score 0):

You want to keep track of one or more elements.  So you need a collection of elements rather than a single element.

Replace

```
double element = 0;
```

with

```
vector<double> element;
```

---

Then, instead of this

```
if (tempFreq > freq)
{
    element = tempElement;
    freq = tempFreq;
}
```

Try something like this:

```
if (tempFreq > freq)
{
    // Empty element vector

    // Add tempElement to element vector

    freq = tempFreq;
}
else if (tempFreq == freq)
{
    // Add tempElement to element vector
}
```

---

Finally, loop through the `element` vector to display each member.

---

Also note that if `freq` is `1` in the end, all the elements are occurring once.  You currently display `"no mode"` in that case.  You probably want that to happen when `freq` is `0`, not when it's `1`

Comment: when u say add tempElement to element vector do u mean push_back ?

Comment: Yes, that is one way to do it.

Comment: it didn't work for some reason, so what i did is that i changed my element to a vector of doubles, i did element.push_back[tempElement] in both if statements that u showed me, then i iterated through the element vector and printed every element at the iterator, it printed some weird values tbh so idk

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your code - but if you actually do what I suggested above, it will work.